# Using google-chrome in docker

Tags: docker, google-chrome

I had problem with using google-chrome on docker container:
WHEN I use:
`google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu http://www.wp.pl`
THEN I got:
`ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory`
AND
`WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.`

I tried with --hedaless=new and it's look like:
`google-chrome --headless=new --no-sandbox --disable-gpu http://www.wp.pl`
And only problem I have with:
`Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.portal.Settings.Read: object_path= /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop: unknown error type:  [436:560:0721/065519.597607:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory [436:560:0721/065519.597994:ERROR:bus.cc(399)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory [0721/065520.915802:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)`

I expecting to see html code just like useing CURL

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-features=dbus http://www.wp.pl

Comment: Unfortunately still see dbus errors in output with that flag on chrome `120.0.6099.216`:
`[1620:1639:0112/011042.362218:ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory`